# Understanding a function that reads data from a serial port

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I'm struggling to understand what is happening in part of an Arduino program I wrote, I copied the switch in processInput from another post about reading data from serial ports but have changed it a bit since then.

To me it seems like the output to the LCD screen should always be 0 since recievedNumber is set to 0 at the beginning of the function, it does output the data from the serial port correctly though. I'm also not sure what is happening on the line "receivedNumber += b - '0';" inside the last case.

Any advice or a breakdown of the logic would be appreciated, I intended to replace the last case with an if statement to learn how to do it without using the GNU extension but I just don't understand what is happening.

An example of data in the serial port:
<45,56><55,54>

Sorry if this is the wrong place but it felt too related to programming to post on the Arduino StackExchage.

```
const char startOfNumberDelimiter = '<';
const char middleOfNumbersDelimiter = ',';
const char endOfNumberDelimiter   = '>';
  
void processNumberC (const long c)
  {
  lcd.setCursor(10,0);
  lcd.print(c);
  lcd.print("C");
  }
  
void processNumberG (const long g)
  {
  lcd.setCursor(10,1);
  lcd.print(g);
  lcd.print("C");
  }  
  
void processInput ()
  {
  static long receivedNumber = 0;
  
  byte b = Serial.read ();
  
  switch (b)
    {
    case middleOfNumbersDelimiter:  
      processNumberC (receivedNumber); 
      receivedNumber = 0; 
      break;

    case endOfNumberDelimiter:  
      processNumberG (receivedNumber); 
      break;

    case startOfNumberDelimiter: 
      receivedNumber = 0; 
      break;
      
    case '0' ... '9':           
      receivedNumber *= 10;
      receivedNumber += b - '0';
      break;

  } // end of switch  
}  // end of processInput

void loop() 
{
  while (Serial.available ())
    processInput ();
}
```

Comment: What does `gdb` tell you?

Comment: your code does not even compile

Comment: I haven't heard of gdb, I'll check it out
It doesn't compile because I tried to only leave what's relevant to the question, the full thing is here https://github.com/ZacC93/LCDTempDisplay/blob/main/LCD/LCD.ino